# Is it possible to access other array elements than the given by the index from the for loop using target?

Tags: c++, openmp

I understand well, I think, why it is possible to access `A[i]` rather fast using all the threads in a GPU. In the following `0<=A[i]<N`.

However, what about the locks and `B[x]` in the following code? Will two access to `lock[1]` and `lock[2]` not block for each other so I don't get any parallelizing at all?

```
const int N=10000;
int A[N];
bool B[N];
omp_lock_t *lock = new omp_lock_t[N];
....
int i,x;
#pragma omp target data map(to:A,B)
#pragma omp parallel for private(x,i)
for(i=0,i<N,i++) {
  x=A[i];
  if (omp_test_lock(&lock[x]) {
    if (B[x]) {
        B[x]=false;
        do_stuff(i);
    }
    omp_unset_lock(lock[x]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot it I will correct it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will two access to lock[1] and lock[2] not block for each other so I don't get any parallelizing at all?

Locks are independent.  A thread holding one lock locked will not prevent other threads from acquiring different locks.

Even so, if your code has to make use of locks to function correctly then that will slow it, possibly even to the point where a serial version performs better.

It is also a bit suspicious that you (think you) need so many locks. And it is more suspicious that you use `omp_test_lock()` instead of `omp_set_lock()` -- you should consider whether you are really ok with the `do_stuff(i)` going unperformed if the wanted lock is not immediately available.  It seems likely that that will make the result of the computation non-deterministic.

Comment: Locks require some memory and if x=1 for one thread and x=200 for another thread, they might not be on the same cache line. And where are they allocated? It is on the host then a lot of traffic takes place between the host and the GPU which will hamper the advantage of using a GPU. You can have a A[0]==1 and a A[500]==1 then I only do_stuff for the first discovered for instance i==500 but never both.

Comment: @user2304458, `lock[1]` and `lock[200]` almost surely are not on the same cache line.  As for their location, I would expect the array of which they are elements to reside in main memory, just like any other object declared by the program.  Yes, that may have performance implications.

Comment: What about B[x]? If you have two threads i==0,A[0]==10, and i==500, A[500]==11 will the access to B[x] be parallel? I mean the transfer goes through a shared bus I assume so only one B[x] at the time is that correct? So that is also a performance implication.

Comment: OpenMP has much less magic than it sounds like you make think it has.  It will not cause objects to be allocated in a different place than they would be in a serial program.  It will not serialize access to objects from within parallel regions unless applicable OMP directives require it to do so.  If directives and compile options so specify, and the OpenMP implementation supports it, then it may use a GPU for some computations, but it will not automagically translate arbitrary code from CPU-directed to GPU-directed.

Comment: B is transferred to the GPU but wherein the GPU compared to A?

Comment: That is unspecified, @user2304458.  Nor is it specified, as far as I am aware, whether either `A` or `B` is copied in full to the GPU under any particular circumstance.  If you want fine control over this sort of thing then you will want to use a lower-level abstraction than OpenMP provides.

Comment: All right. Instead of locks, I can do an array reduction so my host receives an array of those "i" for which A[i] is different. The transfer of the array from GPU to host is serial but it seems I cannot avoid some serial work anyway. Thank you for your patience.